# Sparse Voxel Octree Smooth Meshing

Tags: 3d, mesh, voxel, octree, marching-cubes

I've been looking over several searches on our God Google, and haven't found any article that explains, in a intuitive way, the following question:

> ```
> "How can i smoothly mesh a Octree of voxels?"
> ```

I know how a octree works theoretically (never implemented one "yet"). What i want is an algorithm approach of how to take that nodes data, and generate a smooth, triangle-based, Mesh, like Marching Cubes does (I don't even know if a octree uses a marching cubes...).

Basically, i wanna know how to connect vertices from multiple scales of "cubes" together.

In a Minecraft-like space (where Earth is flat), for Marching Cubes, it is easy to do, because it considers all cubes in the same size, but in a octree, a child node has half the size of it's parents. How can i mesh these different cubes?

Any explanation/link/whatever would be appreciated!

Comment: Maybe this answer will help you: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/66726/18381

Comment: Nice! I'll take a look into these papers. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

[Marching Cubes](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/polygonise/) can work on an independent 3D grid once the [Octree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree) subdivision is completed.

Comment: Thx for reply. I'm going to study around this now. My only question is how you can deal with the edges between a parent and a child, since they are different in sizes, so some faces will cause "holes" in the mesh...

Comment: Marching cubes is simply based on grid nodes being inside or outside the isosurface, it should not be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

The octree will be a 3D volume object not a surface, from such voxel-based object a mesh surface can be extracted using marching cubes.